# I want to deploy back-end and front-end seperate apps on the same server with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, svelte, sapper

I've created a restful api with nodejs and I'm planning to use sapper/svelte for front-end. In the end, these will be seperate apps and I want to run them on the same server with same domain. Is this approach reasonable? If it is, what should my nginx configuration file look like? If not, what should be my approach?

This my conf for api:

```
server {
    server_name domain.name;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: why two apps? Sapper is already doing backend and frontend. You may as well put your api in sapper server routes. Or you could export your sapper app as static to lose the server part.

Comment: I've already created the api. I was thinking about vue or react for a frontend but then I've come across sapper. It'll be my first project with svelte.
I liked the idea of server side rendering for SEO purposes. So, no static export. Maybe I might try to merge it. But is it difficult to configure nginx for double app single domain?

Comment: No, you can do that with nginx. It just feels bloated. You could instead use a plain svelte site or use a different static router for the frontend. Maybe you join the discord chat for more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following best pratice your API will be under BASE/api/

That will allow you to host backend + Frontend on the same server

```
server {
    server_name domain.name;

    location /api/ {    # Backend
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        ...
    }

    location / {    # Frontend
        root        /app-path/;
        index       index.html;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the location block for the frontend doesn't have any proxy related configurations?

Comment: @Ulvi this is just an example, you can always add proxy_pass to that block, if the frontend is deployed in another process/port.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your first svelte / sapper project, I would keep things separate and see if you can get started with svelte to hit the API on nginx. Decouple things and ship [svelte on gitlab pages](https://dev.to/gavinr/publish-a-svelte-web-app-with-gitlab-pages-409i) or whatever other CI destination you prefer.

If it comes time to run with sapper, my advice remains the same - have it hit your API externally to keep your projects clear and distinct. You already launched the API before the front end - no worries, but I don’t see how your config needs to know where the front end will run or why entwining them would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a subdomain for your backend for api.example.com and create another server configuration in nginx. You only need to write a proxy pass for your api ( backend ) because your frontend is going to run on port 80.