# maplibregl in Angular gets CORS error behind NGINX proxy

Tags: angular, nginx, cors, maplibre-gl

My question is about how to configure Angular to allow `maplibregl` to work behind an NGINX proxy used for local development.

This is my proxy to the Angular development server and the local API.

```nginx
http {
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /angular;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:4200;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://web:80;
        }
    }
}
```

Angular runs inside of a Docker container using this command:

```dockerfile
CMD ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host app --port 4200
```

`maplibregl` runs inside of an Angular component:

```dockerfile
new Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'https://vectortiles.geo.admin.ch/styles/ch.swisstopo.leichte-basiskarte_world.vt/style.json',
    center: [19.8, 41.3],
    zoom: 2,
});
```

The first response of vectortiles.geo.admin.ch works:

[image]

But the second one runs into a CORS error:

[image]

Am I using this tile server in a wrong way? Or is the fault my local Docker/NGINX setup. Or perhaps Angular's own `proxy.conf.json`.

It seems only the requests to `world.vectortiles....` are failing:

[image]

Finally here is my `proxy.conf.json`:

```json
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:15001",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    },
    "/tiles/*": {
        "target": "https://world.vectortiles.geo.admin.ch",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    },
    "/mbtiles/*": {
        "target": "https://world.vectortiles.geo.admin.ch",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    },
    "/styles/*": {
        "target": "https://vectortiles.geo.admin.ch",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/styles": "/styles"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried to add config to your proxy vectortiles server?
 location /tiles {
            proxy_pass https://world.vectortiles.geo.admin.ch;
        }

Comment: Please post the exact CORS error text as shown in the the developer tools console.

Answer (score 0):

See if this can help you to rethink the way [I want to deploy back-end and front-end seperate apps on the same server with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208157/i-want-to-deploy-back-end-and-front-end-seperate-apps-on-the-same-server-with-ng/60264817#60264817)

Like you may do

```
http {
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        root /angular;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:4200;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

    }

    server {
        listen 15001 default_server;
        root /angular;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://web:80;
        }
    }
}
```